# loadURL can't work in my second window in Electron.NET

Tags: electron.net

I want to load the URL when the new window is open, but I have an error `ERR_INVALID_URL (-300) loading ' '`

**This is my javascript code**

```js
 function  newWindow(RoomName) {
     const remote = require('electron').remote;
     const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
     const url = require('url');
     const path = require('path');
 
     const videoWindow = new BrowserWindow({
         title: "Video Conference",
         width: 1200,
         height: 660
     });

     videoWindow.loadURL('/new-video-conference/{RoomName}')
     //the url form razor page @page "/new-video-conference/{RoomName}"
 
     videoWindow.on('closed', () => {
         videoWindow = null
     })
     
 }
```